# PHP Not Executing on Command Line

Tags: php

Hello I have php working fine with my apache server. However, when executing the php script from the command line (like `/usr/bin/php file.php`) it just echos the sourcecode of my script back at me, even when executing a PHP in the web directory. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: didn't you change your `php` with `cat`?

Comment: are you sure that executable php file exists in `usr/bin/php`? Have you tried creating batch file and running your code?

Comment: check this: `php <<< "<?php echo 1;"`

Comment: I think libapache2-mod-php5 module is missing

Comment: What does Your script file look like? Maybe You need `<?php` instead of `<?` - check Your `php.ini` file for the `short_open_tag` directive.

Answer (score 3):

Command line scripts STILL need to have at least `<?php` to switch over to PHP mode. Remember that there's really no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files which have a `<?php ... ?>` code blocks within them.

So, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/php

echo 'hello world!';
```

Would actually output

```
echo 'hello world!';
```

because There's no actual PHP code in there. There's just some text that LOOKS like php code. You need to have

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

echo 'hello world!';
```

and then you'll get the expected

```
hello world!
```

as output. Without `<?php` the php interpreter will never "switch" over to actual PHP mode, and just treat all of the text in the file as plain output.

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting this issue for over 4 months and finding nothing to fix it.

My problems started when I installed a new 3T drive and then moved all my projects off the default 1.5T drive.  Could never get anything working right in "localhost" since.  Also cannot get aliases working in the 2 virtual hosts I created, but their index.html files now show fine at:

1. projects.com
2. tbnk-svr.com

But none of the following work:

1. localhost/phpmyadmin,
2. localhost/seopanel,
3. localhost/test.php,
4. localhost/info.php,
5. php on the command line.

I wrote this up at:

```
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/newreply.php?do=newreply&noquote=1&p=6214546
```

and since I get no errors in any of the error logs, can not figure out what is denying localhost and the cmd line from working.  Test of:

```
php <<< "<?php echo 1;"
php -v
```

Both work, so not sure why it is only echoing the file contents as "cat file" would do.

Has to do somehow with it not rendering "localhost"

Cheers!

TBNK

Answer (score 0):

In your past questions, you seem to prefer using short open tags (`<?`), so that is probably the issue. Try running this instead:

```
/usr/bin/php -d short_open_tag=yes file.php
```

If this works, then your current config has short_open_tag disabled. You'll have to edit your CLI config file to change this. You can find the location of the config file using this:

```
/usr/bin/php -i | grep php.ini
```

You should see:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Edit the file listed by "Loaded Configuration File". The line with:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

Should be set to `On`.